# Update an excel sheet using VBA/ADO

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

When I execute this function I get a run time error, "Operation must use an updateable query". What is causing it?

```
Function updateConfigFile(strQuery As String)

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection         
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command

constConfigFile = "MyWorkbookName"

With cnn

    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & constConfigFile & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open

End With

strQuery = "update [test$] Set [test]='Hello' WHERE [Test]='h'"

objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
objMyCmd.CommandText = strQuery
objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

objMyCmd.Execute


Set objMyCmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: What does constConfigFile look like? Could it be missing file-permission to write to that file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get rid of IMEX=1 from your connection string. That works for me.

```
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & constConfigFile & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

Comment: Nice catch! _"IMEX=1; tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might affect excel sheet write access negative."_ http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Comment: Yes, same error.
The possible settings of IMEX are: 0,1,2.
(0 is Export mode; 1 is Import mode; 2 is Linked mode (full update capabilities))