# SQL queries functionality in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, excel

I'm going to write macro 'sql_query' in Excel VBA which give me SQL queries functionality in Excel.

```
sql_query(Query as String;ChosenRange as Range)
```

but how to do that efficienty? Creating ChoosedRange.accdb each time seems to be quite time consuming, what do you think about this.

Assumption: only VBA Excel + libraries

Any clues?

Comment: Use ADO http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: Do you want the SQL query to be something dynamic or are you looking at something to refresh a dataset in your workbook by requerying the database?

Comment: +1 @remou [ADO is the way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002805/update-an-excel-sheet-using-vba-ado?rq=1)

Comment: Looks like Excel 2013 will (finally) add this with a worksheet function [SQL.REQUEST](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sql-request-HP005209267.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211)

Comment: @GTG dynamic, I think it's harder